# Taxi Stand Waiting Time: CDF Calculation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

[image: Problem with solution]

I'm having a problem understanding this solution.

Let's say this solution is correct. If you take the the derivative of the resulting CDF you should get the correspoding PDF. In this case the PDF would be:

$
f_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
  0 & \text{if } x \notin [0, 1] \\
  1-p & \text{if } x \in [0,1]
\end{cases}
$

However when you integrate this function from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ you get:

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1} f_X(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1} (1-p)\,dx = (1-p)x\Big|_{0}^{1} = 1-p \neq 1$

The value of the integral above should be 1, shouldn't it? Does that mean that the CDF in the solution is wrong?

Could someone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: If a CDF is not absolutely continuous, than you cannot  describe the distribution just with a density

Comment: @Henry Ok i think i understand. Probability density functions are associated with absolutely continuous random variables so if a random variable is not absolutely continuous then it can not be decribed by a PDF. Thank you very much